# PHP send mail for multiple users selected from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, email, mysqli

So I'm using PHP like this:

```
if(isset($userID)) {    

$premium = $con->prepare("
SELECT Email
FROM tblName as d       
WHERE Rank = $rank and Type = $type
"); 
$premium->execute();

$premium->bind_result($email);


} else {
    echo "There is no User ID detected, try to refresh browser.";   
}

while ($premium->fetch()) { 

    # SUBJECT (Subscribe/Remove)
     $subject = "New Resume";

    # RESULT PAGE
    $location = "http://www.website.com";

    $sender = "info@website.com";

    # MAIL BODY
    $message = '<html><body>';    
    $message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">';
    $message .= "</table>";
    $message .= "</body></html>";

    $cc = "ss@gmail.com";
    $headers = "From: " . $sender . "\r\n";
    $headers = "BCC: " . $cc . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['Email']) . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

    $to = $email;

    mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers) or die ("Mail could not be sent.");
}
header("Location: http://website.com/");
die(); 

mysqli_close($link);
```

But this not sending email for each selected users. How correctly I could use loop? Should I use `foreach` or improve `while` loop? How could I apply with `arrays` in this case? Could someone get me on correct way? Thank you!

Comment: You are missing the point of `prepared statements` by directly embedding variables within the sql - use placeholders and assign the variables uing `bind_param` in `mysqli` or `bindParam` in pdo. The initial `headers` is over-written with the 2nd line of `$headers ="BCC: " . $cc . "\r\n";`

Comment: you have a lot of mistakes in your code

Comment: @mohade thank you for reply, I would like to hear any suggesstions how to improve code.

Comment: $to = $email from where you get $email and what its content ... second $headers over-written the first one its need (.)

Comment: @mohade `$email` comes from `bind_results`

Comment: im sorry i didn't see it , use fetch assoc in while like this while ($row = $premium->fetch_assoc()) {your-code $to=$row['email'];}

Answer (score 1):

As you are using BCC dont use loop to send mail. 
loop over your query result collect all recipients id and send mail in one call.

BCC: blind carbon copy to tertiary recipients who receive the message. The primary and secondary recipients cannot see the tertiary recipients. Depending on email software, the tertiary recipients may only see their own email address in BCC, or they may see the email addresses of all primary and secondary recipients.

Comment: Thank you for reply, I wont use BCC in production mode, I've used It only for testing purposes right now.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this using foreach loops.

Before using foreach loops save all email address in a single array and iterate over the array to reduce runtime.

You could go the other way round by iterating over the whole data gotten from database.

Your choice.

Comment: Thank you for an answer, but I don't know how correctly to use arrays for that.

Comment: Use `$emails= $premium->fetch_assoc()`

Comment: This wouldn't overwrite `bind_result($email);`? Still I need `while ($premium->fetch()) { }`?

Comment: You wouldn't need all those anymore

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `fetch_assoc()` in the while since if you use that it will fetch all the record one by one and then it will allow to send MAIL as per the requirement that you need.

And you have to concatenate the header in the second line over here because it will overwrite the statements

**Replace:**

```
$headers = "From: " . $sender . "\r\n";
$headers = "BCC: " . $cc . "\r\n";
```

**with:**

```
$headers = "From: " . $sender . "\r\n";
$headers .= "BCC: " . $cc . "\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Prepared statements should take advantage of placeholders to safely assign variables prior to execution

As was pointed out in a comment - if you assign each recipient in the BCC field you can collect the email addresses in the loop but send the email after the loop. This way each recipient will see the `TO` address but none of the other recipients.

```
if( isset( $userID, $rank, $type, $_POST['Email'] ) ) {  

    /* create sql with placholders and prepare */
    $sql='select email from tblname where rank=? and type=?';
    $premium = $con->prepare( $sql );

    /* Only proceed if the prepared statement succeeded */
    if( $premium ){

        /* bind the variables to the placeholders and execute */
        $premium->bind_param('ss',$rank,$type);
        $premium->execute();
        $premium->bind_result( $email );



        $to = "ss@gmail.com";
        $bcc= array( $to );
        $subject = "New Resume";
        $location = "http://www.website.com";
        $sender = "info@website.com";   

        /* collect all email addresses and add to BCC */
        while( $premium->fetch() ) {
            $bcc[]=$email;
        }

        /* close the prepared statement */
        $premium->close();

        /* Close the db connection */
        $link->close();


        $message = '
        <html>
            <body>
                <table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10"></table>
            </body>
        </html>';

        $headers = "From: " . $sender . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "BCC: " . implode( ',', $bcc ) . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags( $_POST['Email'] ) . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";



        $status=@mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );




        die( header( "Location: " . ( $status ? 'http://website.com/?mailsent=true' : 'http://website.com/?mailsent=false' ) ) ); 
    } 
} else {
    echo "There is no User ID detected, try to refresh browser.";   
}
```